# Cannot access a FormControl generated by ngForm from an *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have this code in my template:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form)">
  <input ngModel type="text" name="saveas">
  <button *ngIf="form.value.saveas.length > 0" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

When the page loads, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

But it happens only once, after that *ngIf works as expected, toggling the submit button. What causes the problem? Am I just trying to access the FormControl too early before it's generated by Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template-driven forms are asynchronous](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#async-vs-sync).

> They delegate creation of their form controls to directives. To avoid
>   "changed after checked" errors, these directives take more than one
>   cycle to build the entire control tree. That means **you must wait a
>   tick before manipulating any of the controls**

That also means that `form.value.saveas` value is `undefined` at first time. So to get rid of this error just use safe navigation operator:

```
*ngIf="form.value.saveas?.length > 0"
```